# Displaying JS Alert in a styled modal (jQuery UI) window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

See the code below... And there's a <kbd>[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/JHRtX/)</kbd>.

I want to style this with a jQuery UI. However, will I still be able to call this script, or will I have to embed it directly in the HTML page?

**Here's the form...**

```
<div class="search-pell">
<form onsubmit="showpell_13_14(document.getElementById('pellscore').value); return false;">
    <input type="text" value="Enter 13-14 PELL Score" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter 13-14 PELL Score') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter 13-14 PELL Score'; }" class="search-input-bg-pell" id="pellscore"  />
    </form>
```

Currently, when you search a PELL Grant Score, an alert() is called from another script.

**The script is built out like this...**

```
// Begin EFC Calculator for 2013-2014

function showpell_13_14(efc) {


  var pell;
  var ssg;
  var estpay;
  var monthpay;

    if (efc == 0) {
        pell = 5645;
        ssg = 0;
        estpay = -573;
        monthpay = 0;
    }

    else if (efc <= 100) {
        pell = 5595;
        ssg = 0;
        estpay = -523;
        monthpay = 0;
    }

    else if (efc <= 200) {
        pell = 5495;
        ssg = 0;
        estpay = -423;
        monthpay = 0;
    }
```

**...with the results displaying based on this...**

```
alert('Based on the 2013-2014 EFC you entered ('+efc+'), you may receive...'
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'
                +' \n-Tuition of 36 credits: $14,472' 
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'
                +' \n-Direct Loan maximum for a Freshman* student: $9,405**' 
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'             
                +' \n-Potential PELL Grant Award: $'+pell+'.'
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'
                +' \n-Your estimated total out of pocket payment: $'+estpay+'.'
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'
                +' \n-Potential Student Success Grant: $'+ssg+'.'
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'                 
                +' \n-Your estimated monthly out of pocket payment: $'+monthpay+'.'
                +' \n...'
//              +' \nIf your student has $0 out of pocket, disregard the next few lines...'
//                +' \n_________________________________________________________'                               
//              +' \n-Your estimated monthly payment is calculated by...'
//              +' \n'
//              +' \nTaking your total out of pocket for the year ($'+estpay+')'
//              +' \nand subtracting your Student Success Grant ($'+ssg+') to get'
//              +' \n your overall payment which is then broken up over 9 months'
//              +' \nand comes to $'+monthpay+' per month.'                                                                                                         
                +' \n_________________________________________________________'
                +' \n *Note: This is only configured for 1st year undergraduate students.'  
                +' \n **Loan fees of 1% are included in the loan rates listed on this sheet.');
```

**Again -** I want to style this with a jQuery UI. However, will I still be able to call this script, or will I have to embed it directly in the HTML page?

Comment: You could try to overwrite `window.alert` to redirect the parameters to `jQuery().dialog()`... Though there's something bugging me about rewriting native functions.

Comment: I agree. I don't want to do that. In addition to the modern browsers, this has to be able to work on IE8, too. I don't think I can go that route.

Comment: Good ol' IE as we know it and hate it. That's the disadvantage about `alert`ing a feedback... it's pretty much uncontrollable without altering that native function. If you can, I'd alter the script to return it's result instead. I honestly don't see any other way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window.alert function and the jQuery UI dialogue are not related; the popup is just html. 
The easiest solution to switching to a dialogue is to do the following:

- put a blank div in your html
- initialize it with jQuery UI with autoOpen set to false
- instead of calling alert, replace the html of the blank div with the contents you would put in the alert and then show the jQuery dialog.

Before getting to my example, I have some general advice: don't ever put more than a single function inside an html tag. In general, try to keep your JavaScript and your html separate, as it'll make your (and anyone working with your code's) life easier. And since you're using jQuery, it's better to avoid JavaScript inside tags altogether by using the `.on()` function and binding your functions programmatically.

So I worked on your fiddle a bit, and got the jQuery UI dialog working. I also removed all the javascript from your html.

Lines 1-23 bind function to the form's onsubmit, the textbox's onfocus and onblur, and initializes the jQuery UI dialog (docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)).

Starting from Line 504, I've modified the alert to use the jQuery UI dialog.
I did this by setting the old alert text as a variable and replacing the newlines with html linebreaks so they show up properly in the dialog. And then I inserted the content into the dialog and opened the dialog.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/JHRtX/9/).

Let me know if it all makes sense to you, or if you have any questions :)

P.S. When you use jQuery `$('#pellscore').val()` is way shorter than `document.getElementById('pellscore').value` ;)

## Update

### The Problem

So here's the problem with your current setup: you're using (and relying on) a ridiculously old version of reveal.js. My guess is that you googled "jquery reveal" and came across [this link to zurb's version of reveal.js](https://github.com/zurb/reveal). If that's how you got it, (and most definitely if you got it from somewhere else) you probably didn't notice that a) it hasn't been updated in two years,  b) it uses jQuery 1.4.4, which is three years old, or c) the the bold notice that states that it won't be updated anymore.

Either way, the reason your page breaks is because jquery.reveal.js makes a call to `.live`, which is deprecated since jquery 1.7 and completely removed as of 1.9 .

### The Solution

I hate the idea of patching something that's two years old, but unless you want to rewrite a bunch of code and try integrating the [current version of reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/js/reveal.js) ([source](https://raw.github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/master/js/reveal.js)), I recommend the following quick fix:

Open up jquery.reveal.js, go to line 20, and replace `.live` with `.on`, e.g.
from

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').live('click', function(e)
```

to

```
$('a[data-reveal-id]').on('click', function(e)
```

That should fix your problem. I tried it locally and it seemed to work. Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: It makes sense to me. Tried it and it works great. However (and you might find this has something or nothing to do with the situation), when I place all this into the page (dependencies include jQuery 1.7.1), it doesn't work. When I run it with 1.9.1, then everything else I have doesn't work, and the script you did (in your fiddle) doesn't work either.

Comment: There's a link to my current set up [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/) and I've created a link to the same page with your set up [**here**](http://webfro.gs/south/kb2/index2.html)...

Comment: Forgot to remove authentication from the server. You should be good now.

Comment: I am going to work on implementing the new version of reveal. I thought that's what I had... didn't dig through Github enough I suppose. Your answer works for me. Much thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you're not taking the lazy way out lol. Glad to help :)