# Styling a JS Alert that pops up inside a jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Please see my <kbd>[**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/Tg9zb/embedded/result/)</kbd>...

I wanted a JavaScript Alert to pop up as a jQuery UI Dialog because I want to style it. I got that working, thanks to some help from [@asifrc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877270/displaying-js-alert-in-a-styled-modal-jquery-ui-window).

Now, I'm trying to style that dialog.

**This is what I have for the alert box in my HTML...**

```
<div id="pellalert"></div>
<div class="search-pell">
    <form id="pellform">
        <input type="text" value="Enter 13-14 PELL Score" class="search-input-bg-pell" id="pellscore"  />
    </form>        
</div>
```

The only thing I can do here, is to apply an in-line style the dialog as a whole, like this...

```
<div id="pellalert" style="font-size: 18px;"></div>
```

...but that styles the entire box, and not just what I would like to style. How do I make an `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc., or adding multiple `<br />` between the lines and so forth... is there one overall way to style this?

This is how I have my alert script set up, but I don't see how to add styles in here...

```
/*
    Pell Alert
*/
//Set content to old alert content      
var content = 'Based on the 2013-2014 EFC you entered ('+efc+'), you may receive...'
            +' \n'
            +' \n'
            +' \n'
            +' \n-Tuition of 36 credits: $14,472' 
            +' \n'
            +' \n-Direct Loan maximum for a Freshman* student: $9,405**' 
            +' \n_________________________________________________________'             
            +' \n-Potential PELL Grant Award: $'+pell+'.'
            +' \n_________________________________________________________'
            +' \n-Your estimated total out of pocket payment: $'+estpay+'.'
            +' \n_________________________________________________________'
            +' \n-Potential Student Success Grant: $'+ssg+'.'
            +' \n_________________________________________________________'                 
            +' \n-Your estimated monthly out of pocket payment: $'+monthpay+'.'
                +' \n...'
    //Replace newlines with <br> (since it's now html)
    content = content.replace('\n', '<br>');
    //Set innerHTML of dialog, and then show the dialog     
    $('#pellalert').html(content).dialog('open');

}
```

Comment: instad of using \n use div tags to wrap your content to next line. then you'll be able to style those individually. Additionally you may add certain tags so that you have proper styling as and when required

Comment: It is better to have the content styled in a hidden div and then grab it using jQuery and stick it in the dialog.

Comment: Just put actual html in `content`, rather than just plain text.  You can put divs and spans and headings anywhere you like, and give them class names.  That'll make it possible to style it from a stylesheet.

Comment: I put actual HTML into `content`, and it only displays the first line of markup. See this updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/Tg9zb/3/embedded/result/).

Comment: You didn't close your <h2> tag did you ?

Comment: I just realized that. I responded to your answer, too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needed to keep the current coding, you'd have to create a real "DOM String" directly.

Something like :

```
var content = '<div class="title">Based on the 2013-2014 EFC you entered ('+efc+'), you may receive...</div>'
            +'<div class="credits">Tuition of 36 credits: $14,472</div>' ;
```

And so on...

If you can change the way it is implemented, you should since this code is **not readable enough** (which implies **not maintainable enough**).

One option would be to part your string into functions... each function takes an argument or a few arguments for instance, displays one line or a block, using the arguments... and you append results from different function calls to build your DOM. I can't really show an example of such a function since I don't know your "business logic" needs. But you can probably distinguish various zones in your message, and create functions for each of them.
However, **this is still really complicated** and should not be done.

**The best option** would be to make an Ajax call to retrieve a php file, giving all the arguments needed to the server, instead of building everything in javascript. That would be cleaner. And you would manipulate the DOM much easier.

Comment: And do I write the styles in my stylesheet? How do I call that style sheet?

Comment: Or is inline CSS better for this?

Comment: Depends how much you want to customize the display actually. You could have like one title, one sub-title, a content block, and that would be it. Or you could want to customize each line.

usually better to create a stylesheet. You could name it "popup-msg.css", something like that.

Comment: Here's the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/Tg9zb/4/embedded/result/). I think I've got it from here. You rocked my world Lyth! Much thanks!

Comment: Last question... if I were to create a "popup-msg.css" stylesheet, how would I call it from inside the .js file?

Comment: Check my last update about an ajax call, that could ease your life quite a lot.

Comment: That is a lot easier! Thanks again.

Comment: I recommend you to have an "external" php or html file with the content of your pop-up. This php/html would include the needed css. Javascript will find elements in your DOM with their classes and ids if needed, it does not need to load the css.

Comment: The hard part is that the pop up content will change depending on the number the user enters into the form. PHP is ugly! Not sure how I'm going to do the ajax call just yet, but I'm working on it.

Comment: PHP can do just as good as javascript to determine the content to display. I 'm quite sure adapting your code to PHP will be quite fast, and even if it takes you time, it will be more maintainable.